# Clojure invalid token trying to do divide-by-2

Tags: syntax, while-loop, clojure, token

Trying to do something like this

```
let [N (read)]
(def m 1)
(while (< m*(m+1)/2 N)
       (do m=m+1)
)
println m
```

It doesn't like the `/2` part and says it's an invalid token. Why? How else do you do the division?

Comment: is (/ (* m (inc m)) 2) working? I forgot my REPL at home

Comment: Maybe it is? It isn't liking the next line either apparently so I can't tell

Comment: Let's start with the `(m+1)` bit.  Does that compile?  Also, what is `N`?

Comment: N is a number read from stdin, `let [N (read)]`

Comment: Ok, so you should include that in your example code.  You didn't answer the other question though.  That's important.  Look at the first comment from Jochen.  That's all you need.  Basically, you need to think more in lisp.

Comment: `while` and `do` don't work like that, neither does `=`. Also to print something, you'd need to say `(println m)`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt This seems to work (infinite loop though) `(while (< (/ (* m (inc m)) 2) N)
         
    )`

Comment: in general, the form (a b c) will call function `a` with arguments b and c. So all your forms that calculate things should look like that.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer So to increment `m` I would `(do (= m (inc m)))`?

Comment: This seems to work, is it the right way to do it? `(do (def m (inc m)))`

Comment: may I recommend a book?
https://www.braveclojure.com/foreword/
Is a really good intro

Comment: You are really lost, friend.  I think you should spend some time testing out lisp forms in your REPL.  And yes, read that book ^^.

Comment: What I posted works -- I'm asking if that's the wrong way to do it, and if so, why -- I don't need the snarky side comments about being "lost" please.

Comment: @user8926565 In Clojure it's not a good idea to modify things like you would in other languages like `m = m + 1`. While it is possible to do by calling `def` multiple times, that is not the right way. `def` creates a top-level binding, like a global variable and you're not supposed to redefine it by calling def multiple times with the same variable. Rather use `recur` like @Bill says, or switch to a different looping construct like `reduce`. Also, prefer `let` over `def`.

Comment: @Wodin Thanks for the clarifications / details.

Comment: Also, in Clojure, things like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` are not operators. They are functions. And just like other functions you call them like `(+ a b)`. `/` is used in other places as well, though. It can be used to separate parts of symbols like `Math/PI` or namespaced keywords, like `:your.ns/keyword`. Also in a special type of number called a Ratio like `5/4`. That is syntax for a literal Ratio. Not exactly the same as 5 divided by 4. Try `(type 5/4)`.

Comment: So that must be why it said `/2`was an invalid token? It was interpreting it as  a keyword?

Comment: It would have read `m*` and `m+1` as symbols. I think it would have treated `m*(m+1)` the same as `m* (m+1)`. i.e. Two separate arguments to the `<` function (also, if it had got that far it would have interpreted `(m+1)` as you trying to execute a function called `m+1` with no arguments). Then it would have seen `/2`. I think because of `/` being used in multiple different ways (a symbol on its own, as part of other symbols/keywords) is probably why it was confused rather than treating it as the `/` function followed by a `2`. But you'd probably have to read the Clojure source to be sure why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to solve this in Clojure is with a function and to manage the looping with recur (i.e. recursion).

e.g.

```
user=> (defn f
  #_=>   ([n] (f 1 n))
  #_=>   ([m n]
  #_=>    (if (< (/ (* m (inc m)) 2) n)
  #_=>        (recur (inc m) n)
  #_=>      m)))
#'user/f
user=> (f 5)
3
user=> (f 10)
4
user=> (f 20)
6
```

In the true part of the if form, the recur call recurses with `(inc m)` or m = m + 1. The false part yields the current value of m if the condition is not met.

`recur` is a bit special in that it looks like recursion by appearing to reinvoke the current recur target, but under the hood this becomes a loop.

Other languages like Scheme do this (tail recursion elimination) without the a special form, you would just call the function again.

What's nice about the explicit way the Clojure does it is that if you try to use it in situation where tail recursion elimination cannot be applied, then you get an error and no run-time surprises.

Also notice that there is nothing that looks like an assignment. The function simply computes the value and returns it, which is common in Clojure.

Welcome to Clojure!

Comment: As an aside how do you make sense of where things are with all the parentheses floating around? Maybe I'm new to it but it's hard to read!

Comment: Indentation tells you a lot, it's really not that much different than a curly brace language although it takes some getting used to.